# Calculus with composite functions

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

The diagram above shows the derivative of f(g(x)). I can't seem to understand how we get f(g(x+a)). When doing first principles, when finding the derivative of f(x) we added a small value a, f(x+a). If g(x) is essentially the x in the function f(x) why is it not f(g(x)+a))? Instead it's f(g(x+a)) but why?

Comment: Because argument of $f(g(x))$ is $x$. One more possible notation for composite function is $f\circ g$. With argument it is $f\circ g(x)$, so, small value added to argument looks like  $f\circ g(x+a)=f(g(x+a))$.

Comment: Please enclose your formulas by two dollar signs like `$x^2$` for better display. Also check math jax tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 2):

Because we are taking the derivative with respect to $x$, we want to look at the behaviour of the function as $x$ varies infinitesimally, meaning that we are comparing $f(g(x))$ to $f(g(x+a))$.

We *can* also consider what happens to the composed function when $g(x)$ varies, which we could express as $\frac{df}{dg}$, or $f'(g(x))$, in which case we *would* look at $f(g(x) + a)$, or we might use $f(g(x) + \Delta g(x))$ in comparison to $f(g(x + \Delta x))$. However, this will not be the same thing, which is why we have the chain rule to look at the derivative of composed functions.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to think of $f(g(x))$ as one function taking x as a variable. You can treat the composite function as a single function, i.e for each $x$, we have $f(g(x)) =h(x)$. Then you can consider the derivative definition on the new function $h$.